# Haskell attoparsec: "Failed reading: satisfyWith"

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I want to parse text like `"John","Kate","Ruddiger"` into list of Strings.

I tried to start with parsing `"John",` to Name (alias for String) but it already fails with `Fail "\"," [","] "Failed reading: satisfyWith"`.

Question A: Why does this error occur and how can I fix it? (I didn't find call to satisfyWith in attoparsec's source code)

Question B: How can I make the parser to not require a comma after the last name?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as P
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Control.Applicative(many)

data Name = Name String deriving Show

readName =  P.takeWhile (/='"')

entryParser :: Parser Name
entryParser = do
    P.char '"'
    name <- readName
    P.char ','
    return $ Name (BS.unpack name)

someEntry :: IO BS.ByteString
someEntry = do
    return $ BS.pack "\"John\","

main :: IO()
main = do
    someEntry >>= print . parse entryParser
```

I am using GHC 7.6.3 and attoparsec-0.11.3.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question A: Why does this error occur and how can I fix it? (I didn't find call to satisfyWith in attoparsec's source code)

```
readName =  P.takeWhile (/='"')
```

`takeWhile` consumes as long as the predicate is true. Therefor, after you read the name, `"` hasn't been consumed. This is easy to see if we remove `P.char ','` from the `entryParser`:

```
entryParser = P.char '"' >> fmap (Name . BS.unpack) readName
```

```
$ runhaskell SO.hs
Done "\"," Name "John"
```

You need to consume the `"`:

```
entryParser :: Parser Name
entryParser = do
    P.char '"'
    name <- readName
    P.char '"' -- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    P.char ','
    return $ Name (BS.unpack name)
```

> Question B: How can I make the parser to not require a comma after the last name?

Use [`sepBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.2.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Combinator.html#v%3asepBy).

---

Now your questions has been cleared up, lets make things a little bit easier. Don't consume the `,` at all in `entryParser`, instead, only take the name:

```
entryParser = P.char '"' *> fmap ( Name . BS.unpack ) readName <* P.char '"'
```

In case you don't know `(*>)` and `(<*)`, they're both from `Control.Applicative`, and they basically mean "discard whatever is on the asterisks side".

Now, in order to parse all comma separated entries, we use `sepBy entryParser (P.char ',')`. However, this will lead into attoparsec returning a Partial:

```
$ runhaskell SO.hs
Partial _
```

That's actually a [feature of attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.3.4/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#g:2) you have to keep in mind:

> Attoparsec supports incremental input, meaning that you can feed it a bytestring that represents only part of the expected total amount of data to parse. If your parser reaches the end of a fragment of input and could consume more input, it will suspend parsing and return a `Partial` continuation.

If you do want to use incremental input, use `parse` and `feed`. Otherwise use `parseOnly`. The complete code for your example would be something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as P
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Control.Applicative(many, (*>), (<*))

data Name = Name String deriving Show

readName =  P.takeWhile (/='"')

entryParser :: Parser Name
entryParser = P.char '"' *> fmap ( Name . BS.unpack ) readName <* P.char '"'

allEntriesParser = sepBy entryParser (P.char ',')

testString = "\"John\",\"Martha\",\"test\""

main = print . parseOnly allEntriesParser $ testString
```

```
$ runhaskell SO.hs
Right [Name "John",Name "Martha",Name "test"]
```